# Что такое Integral arg c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
fabs(Integral arg)
```

Что такое `Integral arg`, и где это можно использовать?

З.Ы.

Если не сложно, то с примером, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я правильно понял, то это частично запиленные "концепты". Суть в том, что можно указывать более общий тип. В данном случае Integral - это любое целое - ссылка на стандарт (3.9.1 пункт 7):

> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types shall deﬁne values by use of a pure binary numeration system

То есть, вместо того, что бы писать функцию модуля для каждого типа, просто определяем один раз и компилятор сам подставит все.

Но вот только скомпилировать подобный код мне не удалось, а любые ссылки на функции, которые объявлены с подобным типом, ведут на http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs. А в самом стандарте есть буквально 35 функций, которые определены с этим типом, но только пишется в нижнем регистре.

Answer (score 1):

Если верить [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs):

> 7) Множество перегрузок или шаблон для всех арифметических типов, не покрытых предыдущими перегрузками. Если аргумент имеет интегральный тип (то есть, [`std::is_integral<T>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) есть `true` для этого типа), он приводится к типу `double`. Для типа `long double` возвращаемый тип `long double`, в противном случае `double`.

(приблизительный перевод мой).

То есть, реализация стандартной библиотеки должна предоставить либо шаблон, либо набор перегрузок для *всех* арифметических типов.